# Issue with borders in a Popover customized using UIPopoverBackgroundView

Tags: swift, ios8, popover

I've customized a Popover creating an subclass of `UIPopoverBackgroundView` in the following way:

```
class CustomPopoverBackgroundView: UIPopoverBackgroundView {

    override var arrowOffset: CGFloat {

        get{
          return self.arrowOffset
        }

        set{
        }
     }

     override var arrowDirection: UIPopoverArrowDirection {

        get {
          return UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up
        }

        set {                           
        }
      }

     override init(frame: CGRect) {

         super.init(frame: frame)        
         backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.19, green: 0.19, blue: 0.19, alpha: 1.0)

         var arrowView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "12_24_pop_black"))
         arrowView.frame = CGRect(x: 17.0, y: -11.0, width: 24.0, height: 12.0)        
         self.addSubview(arrowView)
     }

     required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
         fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
     }

     override class func wantsDefaultContentAppearance() -> Bool {
        return false
     }   

     override class func contentViewInsets() -> UIEdgeInsets{
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
     }

     override class func arrowHeight() -> CGFloat {
        return 0.0
     }

     override class func arrowBase() -> CGFloat{
        return 24.0
    }
}
```

I do this mainly because I want to create a popover without the rounded borders by default that Apple provides.

The problem is that inside the Popover I've a `View` with a gray color and I don't know why the `ViewController` is not expanded completely and I can see the borders of the color of the background that I set above in code (black).

Something like this picture of the Popover open :

[image]

I know that you could load borders for the Popover, but in my case I would change the background color of the View in some cases.

What I want to do is expand the `ViewController` displayed as Popover to avoid rounded corners, or I don't know maybe exist a better solution.

How could solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this issue by overriding de following method in the Popover controller

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.view.superview?.layer.cornerRadius = 0
}
```